# ERROR: column reference "page_seq" is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql9.5

таблица

```sql
CREATE TABLE envelope
(
    id      int,
    user_id int
);
CREATE TABLE docs
(
    id_num   int,
    page_seq int,
    doc_text varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO envelope
VALUES (1, 1),
       (2, 2),
       (3, 3);

INSERT INTO docs(id_num, page_seq)
VALUES (1, 5),
       (2, 6),
       (null, 0);
```

Запрос на обновление таблицы

```sql
UPDATE docs
SET doc_text = d.page_seq
FROM docs d
         INNER JOIN envelope ON envelope.id = d.id_num
WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM docs
              WHERE id = envelope.id and d.id_num is not null
          ) ;
```

результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Результат не верный**, *почему-то значение из одной строки, обновило и другие, хотя они и не соответствуют* ????

**Должно быть**

(1, 5, 5)

(2, 6, 6)

(null, 0, null) - **не должна обновляться**

**Обновление**

Выше предложенное решение взято из задач и ответов (SQL server). и запрос гаранитированно должен обновить для каждой строки свое значение.

Comment: Описывайте задачу, а не только свои попытки её решить. Что **должен** делать запрос?

Comment: "_Результат не верный_" .... Да нет, абсолютно верный, запрос написан так что должен обновлять все строки таблицы если найдется хоть одно совпадение по условиям подзапроса. Проблема в том, что фактически у вас в запросе таблица docs участвует три раза, а не два, как вы видимо думаете. Таблица в FROM это не та таблица, которая в UPDATE ! у вас все условия в итоге работают с таблицей во FROM, а на ту что в update нет вообще ни одного условия. запрос думаю должен выглядеть как `update docs d set ... from envelope where envelope.id = d.id_num and exists ...` хотя возможно как то немного иначе

Comment: подзапрос сделан умышленно (так написано в задаче) без алиаса для поля id и по факту просто анализатор будет искать такое поле в других таблицах. данный подзапрос будет сравнивать поля id  в envelope, то есть envelope.id = envelope.id